# NDB Parallel Tasklets

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Please take a look at this parallel tasklet code snippet #1.

```
@ndb.tasklet
def get_data_parallel(e):  
  usr, det = yield (e.user.get_async(),                          
                    MyKind.query(ancestor = e.key).fetch_async())  
  raise ndb.Return((e, usr, det))
```

If e.user is None this raise an Exception.

I'm trying this snippet #2. However I still get Exception: "TypeError: Expected Future, received : None"

```
@ndb.tasklet
def get_data_parallel(e):
  usr, det = yield (e.user.get_async() if e.user else None, 
                    MyKind.query(ancestor = e.key).fetch_async())
  raise ndb.Return((e, usr, det))
```

How can I do something like snippet #2 ? It's possible return future(None) or future('') or something similar ??

Thanks and regards.

Moisés Belchín.

Comment: Moishe, can you add a link to the thread on the mailing list where this was answered?

Comment: For those interested this thread was answered in Google AppEngine Group: 

[link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/fy8aSqiLs0s/VUj_-zZR4tUJ)

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested this thread was answered in Google AppEngine Group:

[Google App Engine group discuss](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/fy8aSqiLs0s/VUj_-zZR4tUJ)

Thanks all.